# copy property file from user.home to project resources folder in compile phase

Tags: java, maven

I have a project.properties file in user.home location. I have small maven java program which reads properties from this property file and perform next functionality.

I am using maven-compiler-plugin to execute my main class whenever I am reading property file which will be in resource folder.

Project packaging is jar. let me know how I can copy file from user.home or any drive location to src/main/resources folder while mvn compile phase.

If it is not possible to copy during compile then how I can copy that file at run time.

Comment: It does not make sense to put something into your home location instead of adding it to your project. This will make your build environment based which will work only on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Put this into your project's POM:

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>${user.home}/project.properties</directory>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

This will package "project.properties" file in the final jar file (well, if you call **mvn package**) and copy it under **target/classes/**.

In addition, you should run your main class by using the [exec maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).